# The value of the integral $\oint_C(2z+1)dz$ on the contour C What is the value of the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

The value of the integral $\oint_C(2z+1)dz$ on the contour C, comprised of line segments C1, C2, . . . , C11 shown in Figure [image: This is the figure]

What is the value of the integral?
I think we can say (2z+1) is analytic, thus this is an independent from path integral and we can use
$\int_{0}^{i}(2z+1)dz$
And our answer will be $i-1$
But how can i say $2z+1$ is analytic. And is my way correct?

Comment: Have you learned about the Cauchy-Riemann equations yet?

Comment: Yes, i know cauchy-riemann equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Polynomials are entire. Then what does Cauchy's Theorem tells us?

Comment: If there is derivative  every point in z_0's neighborhood then f is analytic. That means Cauchy-Riemann equations must provided. And this is enough for an explanation?

Comment: Not Cauchy-Riemann. Have you met with Cauchy's Theorem on integrals?